# Limit of a multivariable function approached along a line and a curve - why are they not the same thing?

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, functions, continuity, 3d

I was studying the limit of a multivariable function. I was given this example: Does $\lim_{(x, y) \to (0, 0)} f(x, y)$ exist, if $f(x, y) = \frac{xy^2}{x^2 + y^4}$?

The solution says if I approach the limit from $y = mx$, where $m$ is the gradient of a linear line, I get $$f(x, y) = f(x, mx) = \frac{x(mx)^2}{x^2 + (mx)^4} = \frac{m^2x}{1 + m^4x^2}$$

So $f(x, y) \rightarrow 0$ as $(x, y) \rightarrow (0, 0)$ along $y = mx$. This includes all the linear lines except for $x = 0$ as $x = 0$ represents the $y$-axis, where $m$ doesn't exist.

Now, if I let $x = 0$ and approach the limit along the $y$-axis, I get $$\lim_{y \to 0} f(0, y) = \lim_{y \to 0} \frac{0}{y^4} = 0$$

Therefore, I have showed that $\lim_{(x, y) \to (0, 0)} f(x, y) = 0$ along all the linear lines in the $xy$-plane, which really tempts me to conclude that $\lim_{(x, y) \to (0, 0)} f(x, y)$ exists.

However, the solution says that if I approach the limit along $x = y^2$, I get $$f(x, y) = f(y^2, y) = \frac{y^2 \cdot y^2}{(y^2)^2 + y^4} = \frac{y^4}{2y^4} = \frac{1}{2} \not= 0$$

Therefore, $\lim_{(x, y) \to (0, 0)} f(x, y)$ doesn't exist.

This confuses me. Because I thought that when I approached a limit along a curve (e.g. $x = y^2$), if I zoomed in enough, according to **linear approximation**, I could view the curve as a straight line and I was effectively approaching the limit along a straight line. **In other words, no matter if I am approaching the limit along a straight line or along a curve, they should give me the same result, shouldn't they?** Can anyone explain what is wrong with this thought? Thank you!

Update on 17 Nov 2023: I am still thinking about this question. And my question can be: I think approaching a point along all straight lines towards that point is enough to cover all directions. But apparently, it's not. Why not? Because near the point the curve is essentially straight if I zoom in a lot.

Comment: The curve $x=y^2$ does have a linear approximation. But that has nothing to do with how good/bad your function $f$ (which is a completely separate object from the curve aforementioned) behaves near and along the curve. So, it seems you’re mixing up different objects (also, side note: linear approximation is a concept for derivatives, not for continuity, so you’re not just mixing up two objects (the curve vs function), but also different concepts (continuity vs differentiability)).

Comment: @peek-a-boo Hello, I got what you mean. However, imagine that I approaching a point a point along a curve. Very close to that point, the path of the curve that I go along is the same as a straight line, isn't it? Therefore, there is no difference between a curveed and a straight path near the point (I suppose)?

Comment: yes, you can approximate the curve (if it is nice enough, which $x=y^2$ is) with a line nearby. But so what? If the function behaves in a willy-wonka way, then the curve being well approximated by the line tells you nothing about how the function is behaving along said curve/line. Continuity is about what the function does near a point, it’s not really about whether all curves through the point can or cannot be approximated by lines/other curves.